# responsive bootstrap grid, buttons being override

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Sorry for very long code. There are 81 buttons i placed in a grid. The problem I am facing is that buttons on the left are being "eaten" to some extention in mobile version and I can not find a reason why. Please see the image:

[image: mobile image]

And the second question is. Why are there spaces between a group of buttons? I always made sure there is padding and margin set to 0px !important. I would appreciate your help

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0px !important;">
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;"></div>
    
     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
        </div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0px !important;">
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;"></div>
    
    
    
    
     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
        </div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="padding:0px !important;">
        <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;"></div>
    
    
    
    
     <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
      <div class="row" style="margin:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="padding:0px !important;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      
        </div>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the column is smaller than the content.
Also, you're setting padding to 0 (in between the 3 'main' columns), bot the margin which is why you have the whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. So is there anyway to adjust the content with bootstrap button?

Comment: I think you simply need more space. You could try to btn-sm or btn-xs classes to get smaller buttons.

Comment: Maybe, make the smallest column a bit bigger, and the biggest a bit smaller?

Comment: Thank you, but I would really need to make content smaller. btn-xs is an option, however I am looking for a way to adjust content to size of col...

Comment: Make a custom btn class in css, which you tell to fill the parent width?